# Manipulate variables to lower and replace spaces with "-"

Tags: jquery

I have some code to replace any instance of ##Some Content## in my page content within #body-inner and replace it with:

```
<span class="tooltipster" data-tooltip-content="#Some Content">Some Content</span>
```

This is working OK, but would like to convert the `data-tooltip-content="#Some Content"` to lowercase and remove the spaces with a "-".

See code below:

```
$('#body-inner').children().each(function(){
        $(this).html( 
            $(this).html().replace(/##(.*?)##/gm,'<span class="tooltipster" data-tooltip-content="#$1">$1</span>')
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`replace#String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function. Although you can avoid [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method by using a callback with [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```
// use html method with callback which iterates over the element where old html is the second argument
$('#body-inner').children().html(function(i, html) { 
  // replace all match substring
  return html.replace(/##(.*?)##/gm, function(m, m1) {
    // generate the html string
    return '<span class="tooltipster" data-tooltip-content="#' + m1.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-') + '">' + m1 + '</span>';
    // instead of split and join, you can also use .replace(/\s/g, '-')
  });
});
```

```js
$('#body-inner').children().html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/##(.*?)##/gm, function(m, m1) {
    return '<span class="tooltipster" data-tooltip-content="#' + m1.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-') + '">' + m1 + '</span>';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body-inner">
  <div>##abc def##</div>
  <div>abc ##def dfdfd## ##fdfdf sdsds##</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I was looking for.